# PySpark get max and min non-zero values of column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|  label|              app_id|               title|download_count|entity_id|risk_score|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|ANDROID|com.aaron.test.ze...|          Aaron Test|             0|      124|       100|
|ANDROID|com.boulderdailyc...|Boulder Daily Cam...|           100|      122|       100|
|ANDROID|com.communitybank...|     Budgeting Tools|             0|      123|       100|
|ANDROID|com.communitybank...|   PB Mobile Banking|           600|      123|       100|
|ANDROID|com.mendocinobeac...|Mendocino Beacon ...|            10|      122|       100|
|ANDROID|com.profitstars.t...|Johnson City Mobi...|           500|      123|       100|
|ANDROID|com.spreedinc.pro...|Oneida Dispatch f...|          1000|      122|       100|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

I wish to get the non-zero max and min `download_count` values grouped by entity ID. I'm not too sure how to do this with aggregation, of course simple max and min won't work.

```
apps_by_entity = (
        group_by_entity_id(df)
        .agg(F.min(df.download_count), F.max(df.download_count), F.count("entity_id").alias("app_count"))
        .withColumnRenamed("max(download_count)", "download_max")
        .withColumnRenamed("min(download_count)", "download_min")
    )
```

as this will get 0 for the min of entity 123 and 124.

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------+
|entity_id|download_min|download_max|app_count|
+---------+------------+------------+---------+
|      124|           0|           0|        1|
|      123|           0|         600|        3|
|      122|          10|        1000|        3|
+---------+------------+------------+---------+
```

The desired output would look something like

```
+---------+------------+------------+---------+
|entity_id|download_min|download_max|app_count|
+---------+------------+------------+---------+
|      124|           0|           0|        1|
|      123|         500|         600|        3|
|      122|          10|        1000|        3|
+---------+------------+------------+---------+
```

Is there a way to do this with aggregation? If not what would be the best way to get this non-zero value? In the case of `max = min = 0` just returning `0` or `null` would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can exclude zeros while doing min, max aggregations, without losing counts. 
One way to achieve your output is to do (min, max) and count aggregations separately, and then join them back.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

min_max_df = df.filter(col("download_count")!=0).groupBy('entity_id')\
                .agg(F.min('download_count').alias("download_min"),\
                F.max('download_count').alias("download_max"))\
                .withColumnRenamed("entity_id", "entity_id_1")

count_df =df.groupBy('entity_id').agg(F.count('download_count')\
            .alias("app_count"))

count_df.join(min_max_df, (count_df.entity_id == min_max_df.entity_id_1), \
        "left").drop("entity_id_1").fillna(0, subset=['download_min',\
         'download_max']).show()

+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|entity_id|app_count|download_min|download_max|
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|      124|        1|           0|           0|
|      123|        3|         500|         600|
|      122|        3|          10|        1000|
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Aha I was about to answer my own question but this is pretty much what I wound up doing, thanks for writing this out